# Signal handler in bash doesnt seem to work

Tags: bash, signals

With the following script running in window1

```
#!/bin/bash

function handler
{
  echo "the time is $(date)" >> /tmp/zz
}

rm /tmp/zz
trap handler USR1
echo "This is $$"
cat
```

In window2 I am sending a signal with "kill -USR1 PID_OF_WINDOW1_SCRIPT"

The `/tmp/zz` file is non existant after I send the signal

I'm pretty sure that this used to work for me in the past
Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shell isn't free to call your handler until `cat` completes. Type an end-of-file character (<kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>d</kbd>) to end `cat`, which lets the shell run your handler and exit.

Comment: Thanks .. I actually just figured it out a minute before (reading http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_12_02.html) ...     cat in this case was just a place-holder for a another long running process that I do not want to kill ... I will use alternate solutions to my need